Is it possible to run a new query with data from another query in grafana?
I have a query (one API call) that returns latitude and longitude fields. I would like to take those two fields and run a separate query (separate API call) to display the address given those coordinates.
Is there anyway I could reference the returned fields I have in the first query and use those to run the second API call?
For example, I'm collecting the below data from one query:

and in theory, I would like to reference those values in query 2 as the input params:

As far as I can tell via my Googling and searching StackOverflow, it's not possible. However I'd like to verify before I give up...

You cannot use results of one panel query as params for another one. But if it is guaranteed that result is always unique, you can get first result into variable(s) and use them in query for second one.
